# Make method testable for unit tests c#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, design-patterns, refactoring

So , i have the following code structure

```
public void method1(int index)
{
   switch(index)
   {
       case 1:
           Method2();break;
       case 2:
            Method3();break;
   }
 }

 public void Method2()
 {
     var entity = new SomeEntity();
     repo.Add(entity);

     var anotherEntity= new AnotherEntity();
     repo.Update(anotherEntity);
 }
```

While covering method2 with unit test, i ran into issue, that if i want to check that entity add to db, anyway it runs an update method too. How i can split it somehow, just wanna get maybe some best practices for method in which it's needed to do multiple operations with db.
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: atomize the method, i guess. get 2 methods inside something like "insert entity" and "update another entity". then test both atomic separately + to have full coverage test method 2 itself

Answer (score 2):

In tests you need to test only behaviour of the object.
In your case behaviour of your object is adding one entity and update another.
Object have public method `Method2` which responsible for this behaviour.

So you ending up with two tests, one for updating and one for adding. 
You can mock a repository and tests that methods `Add` and `Update` called with expected arguments. Or will be better if you can use "InMemory" database and have tests which cover persistence layer as well.

It is ok that `Update` executed also in test for `Add`, you will assert only behaviour of `Add` and ignore `Update` method.

Your problem have nothing to do with Single Responsibility Principle. Single Responsibility Principle means that object should have **only one reason to change**.

In your case if updating another entity is part of logic for adding another one - it should stay in one class/method and been tested as whole.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Method2() violates the single responsibility principle of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

> **Single Responsibility Principle**: a class should have only a single responsibility (i.e. changes to only one part of the software's specification should be able to affect the specification of the class).

These operations need to be in their own methods and in doing so will lead to:

- Better maintainability
- Better options for writing unit tests.

  ```
  public void Method2()
  {
  //This method only adds new entities
   var entity = new SomeEntity();
   repo.Add(entity);
  }

  public void Method3()
  {
   //This method only updates entities
   var anotherEntity= new AnotherEntity();
   repo.Update(anotherEntity);
  }
  ```

Comment: But about SOLID, CRUD it's not related to one responsibility? You mean that method also should have one responsibility e.g either add or update?

Comment: Absolutely. What if you just wanted to update an existing entity? What if you just needed to add a new entity? There is no reason these two CRUD operations should existing in the same method call.

Also consider readability because by having both in the same method, someone else reviewing the code may not be able to follow along easily. Having methods named "AddEntity" and "UpdateEntity" are far clearer to new eyes.

Comment: Okay. And these methods should be called from another one, like wrapper who make both add and update for one operation, right?

Comment: Correct. Your CRUD methods are essentially your data layer. You should also have a business logic layer that calls the methods in your data layer. 

Here's a simple diagram that outlines the basic structure [Repository Pattern](http://www.codecompiled.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/REPOSITORY-PATTERN-1.png)

Comment: Could you advice some reading about organizing code iin such situations?